# Looping through a dynamic variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add data to several tables from a data set in order to categorize it for a report. In order to put all of the data in the correct category, I am trying to find a way to loop through the titles similar to this pseduocode

`Sub test ()`

`Dim name as string, i as integer`

`For i = 1 to 8`

`name(i) = "Data"`

`Next i`

`End Sub`

From a similar question I saw, it was recommended to use a dictionary, but I do not believe that will help me because I already have the data stored and sorted, I just need to put it into a presentable template to send out each week.e

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code. Name is a reserved name and you haven't declared it as a matrix.

```
Sub test()
    Dim N(1 To 8) As String, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        N(i) = "Data"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but the tables that I am trying to fill with data are pre-made in a template that I created for this report. I simply want to loop through "N" where "N(i)" is the name of each of the 8 tables I have                 i.e. N1, N2 .... N8. Essentially the code I am trying to write simply tells excel which table to reference when adding the data.

Comment: Now, after reading your comment, I saw that it was pseudo code in your original question. I think I understand your question a bit better now, but that leads to more questions. Are you trying to compose a cell reference from a list of table names?

Comment: So I am just trying to take the Data the corresponds to N1 and put it in the table for N1 and then the same for N2...N8.  There is no list of table names persay, but rather there is a whole worksheet with 8 blank tables that I am trying to fill by using a loop. I can get it to work for one table at a time, but I'd like to go through all 8 consecutively and quickly.